# выборка из нескольких таблиц criteria hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, hibernate-criteria

Вопрос, видимо, не сложный, но не могу понять сам принцип. У меня есть две таблицы со связью "один-ко-многим", но я не знаю как сделать выборку из них используя Criteria и поместить данные в DTO. SQL-запрос выглядит следующим образом:

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.id, DEPARTMENT.name, empl.id, empl.name, empl.age
FROM EMPLOYEE AS empl
LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT ON DEPARTMENT.id = empl.deapartment_id
WHERE empl.age = '15';
```

вот мои ентити:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
public class Department implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name", unique = false, updatable = true, length = 45)
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "departmentId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private Set<Employee> employeesSet;

public Department() {
}

public Department(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Department(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<Employee> getEmployeesSet() {
    return employeesSet;
}

public void setEmployeesSet(Set<Employee> employeesSet) {
    this.employeesSet = employeesSet;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Department{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name=" + name + "}\n";
}
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "deapartment_id", updatable = true)
private int departmentId;

@Column(name = "age")
private String age;

@Column(name = "name", length = 25)
private String name;

public Employee() {
}

public Employee(String name,  String age, int departmentId) {
    this.setName(name);
    this.setAge(age);
    this.setDepartmentId(departmentId);

}

public Employee(int id, String name,  String age, int departmentId) {
    this.setId(id);
    this.setName(name);
    this.setAge(age);
    this.setDepartmentId(departmentId);
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getDepartmentId() {
    return departmentId;
}

public void setDepartmentId(int departmentId) {
    this.departmentId = departmentId;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee{" +
            " id=" + id +
            ", name=" + name +
            ", age=" + age +
            ", departmentId=" + departmentId +
" }\n";
 }
}
```

А вот мой DTO:

```
public class SomeDto2 {

private int departmentId;
private String depName;
private String age;
private String emplName;


public SomeDto2() {
}

public SomeDto2(int departmentId, String age, String emplName, String depName) {
    this.departmentId = departmentId;
    this.age = age;
    this.emplName = emplName;
    this.depName = depName;
}

public int getDepartmentId() {
    return departmentId;
}

public void setDepartmentId(int departmentId) {
    this.departmentId = departmentId;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getDepName() {
    return depName;
}

public void setDepName(String depName) {
    this.depName = depName;
}

public String getEmplName() {
    return emplName;
}

public void setEmplName(String emplName) {
    this.emplName = emplName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SomeDto2{" +
            "departmentId=" + departmentId +
            ", age='" + age + '\'' +
            ", emplName='" + emplName + '\'' +
            ", depName='" + depName + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

Пробовал сделать так:

```
List<SomeDto2> employees  = session.createCriteria(Department.class, "dep")
    .createAlias("dep.employeesSet", "empl")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("empl.age", "15"))
    .setResultTransformer(
            new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(SomeDto2.class)).list();
```

При этом получаю:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: ru.javastudy.hibernate.model.services.db.dto.SomeDto2 cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

Если кто-то знает хороший ресурс по хиберу с примерами кода (особенно по Сriteria), поделитесь пожалуйста, потому что с документации мне много чего пока не ясно.

Comment: Не хибернейнт, но JPA https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence со своими критериями. Хибернейт тоже умеет в JPA

Comment: Как-то странно определить сложное отношение OneToMany (Department.employes), а простое ManyToOne (Employee.department) нет.

Comment: @Sergey Напишите, пожалуйста, подробнее в чем состоит странность? Мне нужно чтобы поддерживалось каскадное удаление сотрудников вместе с отделом, так как предполагается что сотрудники могут существовать только в отделах. Нужно было определить связь ManyToOne?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, судя по типу в левой части присвоения и имени переменной, вам нужны именно сотрудники, но выбирать вы начинаете с отделов. Это странно. Во-вторых, почему бы не сделать отношение двусторонним, заменив `departmentId` в сущности `Employee` на `@ManyToOne department`? В-третьих, вам не нужен left join чтобы получить 15-летних сотрудников. В-четвёртых, `AliasToBeanResultTransformer()` - это угрюмое эхо далёкого прошлого, в 4-м и 5-м Hibernate применяется `Transformers.aliasToBean()`. Наконец, вы уверены, что DTO вам нужен? Цитата из "Hibernate ORM User Guide", глава 26 "Best Practices":

> Hibernate frees the developer from writing tedious Data Transfer
>   Objects (DTO). In a traditional EJB architecture, DTOs serve dual
>   purposes: first, they work around the problem that entity beans are
>   not serializable; second, they implicitly define an assembly phase
>   where all data to be used by the view is fetched and marshalled into
>   the DTOs before returning control to the presentation tier. Hibernate
>   eliminates the first purpose. Unless you are prepared to hold the
>   persistence context (the session) open across the view rendering
>   process, you will still need an assembly phase. Think of your business
>   methods as having a strict contract with the presentation tier about
>   what data is available in the detached objects.

Comment: если я Вас понял правильно: 
List<Employee> employees  = session.createCriteria(
Employee.class, "empl")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("empl.age", "15"))
                .list();
И это работает! Если, конечно, определить двустороннюю связь.

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, отметьте его решением.